# Downloading multiples images from Picasso in Android

Tags: android, download, picasso

I'm using Picasso library to download images from URL. This is my first attempt on Picasso

Scenario : I want to download some images from server and store them into a file. I know how to store into file and retrieve. When I ran the below code, I happen to see that I'm getting only last image. It seems like Picasso runs parallelly. I checked it by displaying a toast message. Is there anyway to solve this issue?

Problem : I'm getting only the last url image.

Here's my code

```
static int  count = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    for (int i = 0; i < url.length; i++)
    {

        // url is String array which has 2 urls. 
        ++count;   // Incrementing the count by 1
        Picasso.with(this).load(url[i])
        .into(new Target() {

            @Override
            public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap arg0, LoadedFrom arg1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                arg0 = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(arg0, 150, 150, true);
                filePath = saveFile(arg0);   // I'm just calling this function to check how many times `onBitmapLoaded` is called. And it is called only once...!!
            }

            @Override
            public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
    }
}

public String saveFile (Bitmap bm)
{

   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ""+count, 100).show(); // Displaying the value of count, which always display as **2**. 
   return "";
}
```

Comment: Yes it always show count 2 becz when your first image bitmap loaded at time count has reached value 2 in iteration.

Comment: You're absolutely right. Thank you @Haresh. So I can save many number of images into files with this code?

Comment: i posted ans now you can check and more clear about it.

Comment: ,have you check out my ans ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

```
static int  count = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    for (int i = 0; i < url.length; i++)
    {

        // url is String array which has 2 urls. 
        Picasso.with(this).load(url[i])
        .into(new Target() {

            @Override
            public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap arg0, LoadedFrom arg1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                arg0 = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(arg0, 150, 150, true);
                ++count; // Incrementing the count by 1
                filePath = saveFile(arg0);   // I'm just calling this function to check how many times `onBitmapLoaded` is called. And it is called only once...!!
            }

            @Override
            public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
    }
}

public String saveFile (Bitmap bm)
{

   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ""+count, 100).show(); // Displaying the value of count, which always display as **2**. 
   return "";
}
```

Comment: You should be using a dedicated thread and using `.get()`, not `.into()` for this.

Answer (score 4):

This is perfect answer and I've tested it and works like a charm.
You need to use a dedicated thread to retrieve multiple images from network.

```
private class loadImg extends AsyncTask<Void,Integer,Void> {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {
                for(int i=0;i<mAdapter.getItemCount();i++){
                    Object object = mAdapter.getItem(i);
                    final String link = object.getImageLink();//"YOUR IMAGE LINK OR STRING";
                    if(link!=null && !link.isEmpty()) {
                        Bitmap bitmap = Picasso.with(context).load(link).get();
                        publishProgress(i);
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
            mAdapter.notifyItemChanged(values[0]);
            super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        }
```

Call your AsyncTask any where in the Main thread.

```
new loadImg().execute;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Picasso.with(MainActivity.this).load(Uri.parse(card.getField("profile_picture_url"))).into(viewHolder.tvPersence);
```

use this code in your `getView()` method.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the method in this way rather make a call and depending upon the response call the next call .
Like method1 -> error(), result

Handle the list of url at both of them and call the same method.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get you. Can you please expound? Or a pseudocode ?

Answer (score 0):

```
Picasso.with(context).load(url).into(imageview);
```

in this approach image loading is depends on the speed of your internet to download the image..

Answer (score 0):

```
    final ImageView iv = new ImageView(context);

    Picasso.with(context).load(resultImageUrl).into(iv, 
       new Callback() {
           @Override
           public void onSuccess() {
              // Picasso successfully loaded image from resultImageUrl

              Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) 
              iv.getDrawable()).getBitmap();

              ImageStorage.saveToSdCard(context, bitmap, imageName);

              onFinishDownloading(results);
           }

           @Override
           public void onError() {
              // Picasso has failed to load image from resultImageUrl

              onFinishDownloading(results);
           }
    });
```