# Downloading multiple images using Picasso Progress/Complete

Tags: android, progress-bar, picasso

I've found some things that are similar but nothing that answers this. 
[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26425549/is-there-a-way-get-the-progress-of-the-queued-downloads-in-picasso) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24822086/downloading-multiples-images-from-picasso-in-android) are similar.

I'm looking to download a fixed amount of images which I'll call x.  While downloading I want to display a determinate `ProgressBar`. When x images is downloaded I want to remove/hide the `ProgressBar`.

I'm downloading them using `saveBitmap(_picasso.load(url).get());`

**1.**  So the question is how can I call my method `hideProgressBar()` after all images are downloaded?

**2.**  Is it possible to have a determinate `ProgressBar` with Picasso?  If not, is there another library that does?

Comment: Hi @Exeon, have you found any solution for your 2nd question ?

Comment: No, I think using another library would be the best alternative. I think Fresco would be the easiest to achieve my 2nd question.

Answer (score 0):

I am not acquainted with Picasso. Are you downloading the images sequentially?

If yes, you could simply try something like this for your `doInBackground`:

```
for (int i=0; i<x; i++){
    fetch_image(i);
    publishProgress( (i/x) * 100 );
}
hideProgressBar();
```

In `hideProgress` you can do `view.setVisibility(false)`, where view is whatever View you are using to show your progress.

Comment: That's really helpful! but I'm looking to solve it specifically with Picasso if I can.